# making dynamic array using Type** &x

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

With respect to the following code snippet for making a dynamic array

```
template <class Type> 
void Make2DArray(Type** &x,int rows, int cols) 
{ x=new Type*[rows]; 
   for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) x[i]=new Type[cols]; 
}
```

How to understand the usage of Type** &x, why it has two **

Comment: After you're done understanding how references work, please make sure you never ever use this snippet in real code and check out the resource-managing containers in the standard library instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type**` is a pointer to a pointer.

`Type**&` is a reference to a pointer which points to a pointer.

`**` will allow you to make an array of an arrays. This can be used for 2d arrays - `x[][]` will work.